# How to inject an object into a class in a jar?

Tags: java, sockets, code-injection

I created a SocketClient object that I have placed into the jar, I want to call it when the java program is ran, so that socket starts and then I can connect to it through an external application. How would I call the object on the start of the program.

SocketClient

```
public class SocketClient {

    private boolean isCon = false;

    public SocketClient() {

    }

    public void communicate() {
        while(!isCon) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localHost", 9090);
                System.out.println("Connected");
                isCon = true;
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                AbstractScript passScript = getAbstractScript();
                System.out.println("Passing Object");
                oos.writeObject(passScript);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public AbstractScript getAbstractScript() throws Exception {
        Class reflectClass = AbstractScript.class;
        Object construct;
        construct = reflectClass.newInstance();
        AbstractScript newAbstractScript = (AbstractScript) construct;
        return newAbstractScript;
    }

    public boolean isRunningScript() throws Exception {
        Method method;
        Class reflectClass = AbstractScript.class;
        if(reflectClass != null) {
            method = reflectClass.getDeclaredMethod("isRunning", Boolean.class);
            try {
                Object returnValue = method.invoke(null);
                Boolean value = (Boolean) returnValue;
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I created a SocketClient object that I have placed into the jar." What does this mean? You made a class and compiled it? If so, it will be loaded by the classloader as long as the jar is on your classpath. In that case, you can instantiate a `SocketClient` object in your application and call it like you would any other way.

Comment: I have an external application that I'm adding functionality too, I'm assuming just by placing the .class file into the jar it won't be ran if its not called. I need to call It, but don't know how.

Comment: Generally, to get an object in a jar, you do most of the construction outside and then erect it inside by tugging on the rigging.  Though some folks claim to have used forceps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a simple example that can help you do what you want.

Assume that you compile the `SocketClient` class into a jar file called `MySocketStuff.jar` and your external application is packaged into a jar called `MyApplication.jar`

In order to have your external application make use of your `SocketClient` class, you just need to make sure that jar is on your classpath when you run the application, so the classloader will load those classes.

Then you can use the class like you would in any other development environment.

Assume your `main` method has something simple like this:

```
import my.socket.stuff.package.SocketClient;  // you'll need the jar on your class path when you compile this file!

public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // instantiate the object
        SocketClient mySocketClient = new SocketClient(); // create the object
        // do stuff
        mySocketClient.communicate();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Once you compile this jar (and you can decide if you want to include the imported class in the jar or not...), you can call your program from the command line like this:

```
java -cp "<path to MySocketStuff.jar>;<path to MyApplication.jar>" MyMainClass
```

Does this help?

Comment: Is it possible to use reflection on "MyApplication.jar" and send it through the socket with this?

Comment: @JordanFlorchinger I'm not sure what you mean by "on MyApplication.jar", but you can certainly use reflection to create whatever objects you want from your main application, but that really only needs to be done when you don't know the type of your object at compile time, or if the library will not always be present when you run. Seems like a use-case that you're over-complicating, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I'm just referring to the example you provided. I'm going to have multiples of the same application running, and I need to be able to get if they are loaded or not, and in this sense loaded means more than just if a process is visible.

Comment: Seeing as how your original question was "How do i call a class in another jar", this is how you do it. You put the class in a jar, and put it on the classpath. How you instantiate the object is entirely up to you, reflection or otherwise, you just need to have the jar on the classpath. If you don't have it on the classpath, then you will need to use a classloader to read the jar file from the disk and then load the classes yourself.